# htaccess multiple url 301 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

There are many sections in my news website. And contents are in 2 languages: English and Hindi. URL structure is like

```
site.com/city1/123/some-text-here
site.com/city2/123/some-text-here
```

and so on

But I want to redirect these types url to

```
site.com/news/city1/123/some-text-here
site.com/news/city2/123/some-text-here
```

Also there are some exclusions like

```
site.com/hindi/some-text
site.com/election/some-text
site.com/images/some-text
site.com/css/some-text
```

There are few more exclusions. I don't want these urls to be get affected.
Also, all redirection should be 301 redirect because URLs are already got indexed on Google.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Question :You want to redirect your **/city/** folder and all its requests to **/news/city** , You can use the following one liner Redirect for that:

```
Redirect 301 /city/ /news/city/
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for the mistake.
city is a variable in the url. It will be changing accordingly.